# HTML email (from SendGrid) not being rendered properly

Tags: html, email, content-type, sendgrid

What Content-Type does SendGrid set in the header by default?
I have an issue where html email going thru Sendgrid is not being formatted properly.
In the email header I see

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
```

and then the following is rendered in any email client, standalone or web based.

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------e21a5bffb444e61b8e8a30240210d506
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

etc etc

Shouldn't the Content-type in the header be multipart/mixed or similar to properly render the html and display images?
How is this changed?
Can it be changed somehow by the actual html being sent to SendGrid's server?
Any feedback appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to send the email.

Comment: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27
https://code.google.com/archive/p/smtpmailer/downloads

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is hardcoding the `content-type` to be `text/plain`. In the `smtp/mailer/SMTPMailer.as` source on line 135:

```
writeUTFBytes ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\r\n");
```

This library doesn't look like it's extremely robust, it's lacking documentation, and it's 6 years old. You may want to try to find a different solution.